# Can't set sample rate to 44100 Hz when using loopback in ALSA

Tags: linux, audio, alsa, sox

I have set up ALSA like this to play to and record from loopback devices:

```
# output device
pcm.loopout {
  type dmix
  ipc_key 328211
  slave {
    pcm "hw:Loopback,0,0"
    period_size 1024
    buffer_size 2048
    rate 44100
  }
}

# input device
pcm.loopin {
  type dsnoop
  ipc_key 686592
  slave {
    pcm "hw:Loopback,1,0"
  }
}

# duplex plug device
pcm.loop {
  type plug
  slave {
    pcm {
      type asym
      playback.pcm "loopout"
      capture.pcm "loopin"
    }
  }
}

pcm.!default {
    type plug
    slave {
      pcm loop
      rate 44100
    }
}
```

However, when I try to record from loop using e.g. sox, for instance with

```
rec -b 16 -c 2 -r 44.1k test.flac silence 1 0.1 3% 1 3.0 3%
```

I get the message

```
rec WARN formats: can't set sample rate 44100; using 48000
```

I find this very peculiar, particularly since I've set the rate to 44100 in asound.conf.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does it work with `arecord`?